# Duda aplicación cliente/servidor Android

Tags: android, json, sqlite

Estoy diseñando una Aplicación Android en la cual mis dispositivos van a tener una base de datos local cada uno de ellos. Esta base de datos es [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite) y debo de hacerlo porque existe la posibilidad de que los usuarios no tengan Internet ya que es para usarlo en zonas agrarias y posibles lugares **sin conexión**.Se va a ir guardando información de los formularios que el usuario vaya realizando en esta base de datos local.

Tengo que decir que los formularios son bastante extensos y cuando tomo los valores de los distintos apartados de este lo guardo en distintos objetos de distintas clase.

Mi duda:

Tengo que diseñar un servidor que consiga recibir los distintos formularios de los dispositivos (No es necesario que el dispositivo A sepa los formularios del dispositivo B, es decir, que la información solo iría hacia el servidor) y no se como hacerlo.

¿Alguien me podría ayudar?

Comment: Miguel, comentas que sera una bd local ya que podría no existir internet, pero recuerda que también vas a enviar los datos al servidor. Hoy en día sería algo raro definir una aplicación aislada que no tenga que envíar datos vía internet o viceversa.

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es que los datos se mantengan almacenados en tu base de datos local de sqlite y cuando haya conexión a internet se envién los datos al servidor. Una vez que el servidor confirme que se han enviado esos datos, remover los datos de los dispositivos para liberar recursos.

Comment: Yo crearia una variable que sea verdadera o falsa dependiendo si ya se han guardado los cambios. por ejemplo:
si hay cambios sin guardar en servidor= verdadero,
si hay cambios guardados en servidor = falso.
Solo tendrías que verificar esta variable guardada en las preferencias cada que inicies la actividad, y si es verdadera llamar al método para guardarlo en el servidor.

Comment: Muchas aplicaciones realizan lo que comenta Luiggi, almacenan los datos y al tener conexión los envían, solo que regularmente son los datos actuales o los últimos que fueron modificados, Hay que evaluar ya que si quieres enviar una gran cantidad de datos que se almacenaron previamente, puede crear algunos problemas.

Comment: Mi duda sobre todo viene en que tecnología debería de usar para crearme el servidor, ya que nunca he realizado una aplicación de este estilo.

Comment: Hola Miguel, el lado del servidor lo puedes crear con casi cualquier cosa, pues es aconsejable hacerlo con una REST api o algún servicio web similar.. Alguna vez hice algo similar, y lo complicado es definir un mecanismo para resolver los conflictos (ej. dos clientes modifican el mismo registro). Por lo demás, cada cliente debería llevar un LOG de cambios, es decir un registro de todo lo que se modifico localmente y luego aplicar esos cambios en la base principal. Otra opción es comparar las bases pero esto requiere mucho ancho de banda y tiempo, no resulta practico.